# Implementing Dojo Widget

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget

I am new to Dojo and was asked to look at creating a widget. The widgets will be on different pages and has to read the page info using the meta data. Based on the meta data value it should pulls a list of content to display of the page from the database. I would get suggestion on where should I start first and how to proceed. Any samples or similar widget examples would be of help.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by saying it has to "read the page info using the meta data". A Widget constructor has meta data, but it is only pertinent to the widget. Perhaps I'm not understanding what you mean by _page info_. What is the meta data value that is driving your database access? Implementing a custom Dojo widget is fairly simple, but some elaboration about what you are trying to achieve would really help.

Comment: Here is the page for **[creating a custom widget in dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/writingWidgets.html)**.

Comment: jessemon, why dont you put your comment in an answer ?!? i am tempted to do that for you :-D

Comment: Jessemon, The widget will be on different pages and it will try to show data on that page based on the meta data value of the page. It might look at the meta data to see what product the page is related to.

Comment: Jessemon, please put your comments as answer so you can get credit.